# gridrow that has visibility set to collapsed, still reserves a black spots

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I am trying to place an ad grid for my panorama view.

The problem is that when i'm trying to hide the ad grid by setting the visibility to collapsed(when the app isn't 'trial'), i can't see the ad anymore but i see a reserved black space the size of the ad. Here is my code:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7.WPF;assembly=Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7"  xmlns:my="clr-namespace:adMob7;assembly=adMob7"  
    x:Class="WP7SQLiteClient._MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WP7SQLiteClient"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="696"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <controls:Panorama Grid.Row="0" x:Name="panoramaMain" SelectionChanged="Panorama_SelectionChanged">
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="messages">


            </controls:PanoramaItem>
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="share">

            </controls:PanoramaItem>
        </controls:Panorama>

      <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Yellow" x:Name="grid" Margin="0" Visibility="Collapsed" >
    <adduplex:AdControl x:Name="ad" Margin="0" xmlns:adduplex="clr-namespace:AdDuplex;assembly=AdDuplex.AdControl.Silverlight"
                        AppId="7671" 
                        />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

How can i hide or remove the ad without having the black space reserved?

Comment: Could you show the Row definition?

Comment: @Erno  there is no row definition

Comment: Then how can you do this: `Grid.Row="1"`

Comment: i don't have a very strong definition of XAML so i thought if there wasn't a RowDefinition, it would have just been ignored.

Comment: Yes, it will be ignored but it will now be put on top of the Panorama.

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru I'm having the same trouble, did you ever find a solution to this? Many thanks

Comment: @TripVoltage i remember i did find a solution, but i can't remember what it was, sorry.

Comment: @TripVoltage you could try removing the row (if you don't use it anymore) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196118/remove-and-add-gridrow-definitions-in-c-sharp is removing it a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Grid Row that contains the control will collapse too:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <myControl Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

The second row containing the control will now collapse. When the Height is set to "*" the row will still be 'visible'.

Comment: If you are setting the row height to "Auto" it may be desirable (depending on the situation) to define a MaxHeight as well, just in case the content gets silly.

Comment: The grid still doesn't collapse. even when my control is set from the start with the visibility collapsed, there still is that space reserved

Comment: if i set the height from 'auto' to '30', i can only see 30px of my control, but there is still space reserved on top of it(i.e. if the initial reserved space was 80, if i display 30px, there still are 50px of blank space reserved)

Comment: Show us the entire XAML, I am shooting in the dark here. There might be something else in the Grid cell/Row

Comment: What happens when you set the Margin of the AdControl to `0`? I suspect the control of having a default margin. Another way of testing would be to put the AdControl in a nested Grid and give the Grid a good visible Background color. Opening the app in Blend could also help in determining where the gap comes from.

Comment: @Erno thanks for the tips but they didn't work for me. I've updated the code and i still see a reserved space there that isn't my color (i.e. Yellow in this case). I just can't get it to work!

Comment: If it is not 'your' color it must be the adControl that is claiming this space. You could try setting its Padding property to 0. If that does not work you should contact the publisher of the control.