# Remove and add GridRow definitions in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have a Grid with RowDefinitions defined in XAML that I need to change when going to snapped view in code, and so far I can only figure out how to remove them via:

```
RowDefinitionCollection defs = mainGrid.RowDefinitions;
defs.RemoveAt(0);
defs.RemoveAt(0);
```

Essentially I need to remove all definitions in snapped view (above code works) but then need to make the first row have a height of 140 and the second be "*" once it goes back into snapped. How would I add definitions with these characteristics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    RowDefinitionCollection defs = myGrid.RowDefinitions;
    defs.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(140) });
    defs.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
```

Alternatively, you could have two Grids and just modify the Visibility as part of the visual state, then you're not pulling a lot of tedious UI manipulation into your code. The built-in Visual Studio templates use this technique for snapped view.

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
RowDefinitionCollection rdc = mainGrid.RowDefinitions;

rdc.Clear();

rdc.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(140) });
rdc.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
```

Answer (score 0):

myGrid.Children.Clear();

remove all child controls